# XCode debugger weird behavior

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging

I have an iPhone app that I am trying to debug.

One of my method returns a wrong value only when executing code, in the debugger it is fine.

```
int finalResponse = 0;
finalResponse = [data getInteger:@"final_response"];
```

then in the debugger

```
p finalResponse  
(int) $0 = 130450628

p [data getInteger:@"final_response"]
(int) $1 = 0
```

I am expecting the 0 value, the other one is garbage. I don't understand why it yields different result depending on how I execute the function.

edit:

getInteger returns an int
It uses an underlying c library which returns a (const void*), like this

```
int* value = get_dictionary_value("final_response", dictionary);
int val = (int) *value;
return val;
```

Comment: I'm guessing your breakpoint is set after both lines of code have run? If your breakpoint is on finalResponse=  the statement has not yet been run.

Comment: yes, this is not the uninitialized value =)

Comment: If you put the breakpoint at the line where you initialize finalResponse, the debugger will step there *before* the instruction is executed, and not after.

Comment: thats funky stuff. I bet its a some linking issue with the debugger. Try restarting Xcode and if that doesn't work try rebooting.

Comment: @atreat : rebooting was a good idea but it didn't help

Comment: thats very odd. Are any errors thrown if you try to use the finalResponse variable after its 'set'?

Comment: @atreat there is no throw, everything is in a try / catch block

Comment: is the catch being run? And are you implementing your own getInteger?

Comment: the catch is never it, the getInteger is personal code, yes

Answer (score 3):

Does the [poorly named -- shouldn't have a `get` prefix] `getInteger:` method do anything like advance an index into `data`?

Or does `getInteger:` return an NSNumber?

How is `getInteger:` implemented?

With just that code, it is hard to say.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes I experience weird debugging behavior when I debug using a release build; make sure you're using the right build phase for debugging.